# bumper exports -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Source: http://foreignpolicy.com/2014/12/05/can-anything-save-the-ruble-russia-economy-putin-oil/

> At the moment, Russia is probably shipping 5 to 6 million barrels of oil abroad every day. That’s as much as one-third more than it exported last year. Its daily oil production is holding at around 10 million barrels, with no cuts in sight; unless domestic consumption were to spike — unlikely with the Russian economy on the verge of recession — those **bumper exports** will continue.

How do you understand that phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Bumper* <sup>[1](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/bumper_5), [2](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bumper)</sup> here means *unusually large and successful*, and is often used this way in the context of production yields.

You can see from the context that Russia's oil production is much larger than usual - 5 to 6 million barrels a day, *33% more than last year* - which means they are generating substantially more export revenue than usual. Thus, oil is a *bumper export* for Russia.